# preg_match inconsistent behavior

Tags: preg-match

I have created a regex to match the urls supported by Fitvids.js. So this regex validates
iframe codes from youtube,vimeo,blip,viddler & kickstarted.

```
\#&lt;iframe.+(youtube|vimeo|blip|viddler|kickstarter).+<\/iframe>#i
```

Unfortunately, any regex validator validates this with urls but the strangely php's preg_match function gives a false in result.

It would be really helpful if anyone can give me solution and why are there so many inconsistencies among PHP Regex and other perl regex results. Also why is that ereg (which is soon to be depricated) gives a correct result whereas preg_match does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply because `ereg` is not PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) but `preg_match` functions are. Expect weird behavior from any function that is deprecated.

Comment: Unfortunately I want this wierd behavior form preg_match as well :P